# STR_TO_DATE returning incorrect hour value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-workbench

I have a date column that has the date and time stored in string format in my sql database. I am trying to convert to a proper date-time field, but when I use the STR_TO_DATE function it is only reading the 2nd digit of my 2 digit hour field.

For example

```
SELECT '2018-11-26 15:55:58', STR_TO_DATE('2018-11-26 15:55:58', '%Y-%m-%D %T')
```

is returning:

```
'2018-11-26 15:55:58', '2018-11-26 05:55:58'
```

I am trying to understand what I'm doing wring, the hour is being incorrectly calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use `%d` (*Day of the month, numeric (00..31)*) instead of `%D` (*Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)*).

Apparently it considers two characters after 26 as the ordinal suffix.

Comment: Cheers, that fixed the problem!